# Whats the intergral of xe^-y dy dx with 0 and 1 as limits

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

This question has one integration sign:

$$
\int_0^1 xe^{-y} \; dy \; dx
$$

How do I solve such a question

Comment: It is very hard, not to say almost impossible, to know/understand what you really mean. Check the following to learn quickly how to properly write mathematics in this site:http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Often a second symbol is omitted, though it is a bit ambiguous in this case. I'd read it with [0,1] for both integrals. But reading it as an indefinite integral over x might be valid too.

Comment: thanx @DonAntonio for the link

Comment: It's a typo.  Each integral symbol needs to be paired with a differential (like $dy$, $dx$, etc.).

Comment: Can you do $\int_0^1xdx$? Can you do $\int_0^1e^{-y}dy$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an integral requires integration over several variables, but only a single bound on the integration is provided, it is implicitly for each variable. Thus,

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 xe^{-y} \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 x\left(1-\frac{1}{e}  \right) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)$$

Comment: *Really?*  That is lazy.

Comment: You can write $\int_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} f(x,y) dA$ or even $\int_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y) dA$ if it's clear that $dA = dx \wedge dy$, but the **dimensions** need to match!

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple separable equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=xe^{-y}$$
Times both sides by $\mathrm{d}x$ to get...
$$\mathrm{d}y=xe^{-y}\mathrm{d}x$$
Divide both sides by $e^{-y}$ to get ...
$$\frac{1}{e^{-y}}\mathrm{d}y=x\mathrm{d}x$$
Integrate both sides to find original equation.. You should be able to handle it from there..